# Discord.js v14 - String exceeding expected length of (1024)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm receiving a string error for my `serverinfo.js` slash command that I can't find an answer for. I believe the issue is that the string comes up as longer than the expected length (1024).

Here is the current error I receive when running the `serverinfo` slash command on a server with many roles:

```
CombinedPropertyError (1)
  Received one or more errors

  input[6]
  | CombinedPropertyError (1)
  |   Received one or more errors
  | 
  |   input.value
  |   | ExpectedConstraintError > s.string.lengthLessThanOrEqual
  |   |   Invalid string length
  |   | 
  |   |   Expected: expected.length <= 1024
  |   | 
  |   |   Received:
  |   |   | '<@&289463765118746636>, <@&368715035410956289>, <@&289485329277255690>, <@&390953914662649856>, <@&534842283422384133>, <@&415871527607730176>, <@&609326498863906829>, <@&489773200734158848>, <@&369558361508675584>, <@&534842280826241024>, <@&382268555514609674>, <@&534842279991443456>, <@&607222382134034433>, <@&430023080342192138>, <@&572746958280589324>, <@&538123328452427807>, <@&424561276035792926>, <@&607150665407397888>, <@&534842282176675843>, <@&538123326921637919>, <@&573859029684846623>, <@&608292634535919637>, <@&538109688441470989>, <@&365555582033461258>, <@&607923580092547086>, <@&606790273745289217>, <@&573855539704889402>, <@&289458849822277632>, <@&534842282709352458>, <@&538109682309529626>, <@&573859302067011584>, <@&411505463843356673>, <@&538109687221190697>, <@&277926713676267521>, @everyone, <@&534842281254060054>, <@&289825650238554114>, <@&369514554356662272>, <@&538109686080339988>, <@&368049921942749205>, <@&538109688714231820>
```

As for the code in question:

```js
const {
  SlashCommandBuilder,
  EmbedBuilder
} = require("discord.js");

  module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
      .setName("serverinfo")
      .setDescription("Provides information about the server.")
      .setDMPermission(false),
  
    async execute(client, interaction) {
      const { guild } = interaction;
      const { members, channels, emojis, roles, stickers } = guild;
  
      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('#2B2D31')
        .setTitle(`Server info - ${guild.name}`)
        .setFooter({text: `Server ID: ${guild.id} | Server Created: ${guild.createdAt.toDateString()}`})
        .setThumbnail(guild.iconURL({ size: 256 }))
        .setImage(guild.bannerURL({ size: 256 }))
        .addFields(
          { name: 'Owner', value: (await guild.fetchOwner()).user.tag, inline: true },
          {
            name: 'Text Channels',
            value: guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type === 0).size.toString(),
            inline: true,
          },
          {
            name: 'Voice Channels',
            value: guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type === 2).size.toString(),
            inline: true,
          },
          {
            name: 'Category Channels',
            value: guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type === 4).size.toString(),
            inline: true,
          },
          { name: 'Members', value: guild.memberCount.toString(), inline: true },
          { name: 'Roles', value: guild.roles.cache.size.toString(), inline: true },
          { name: 'Role List', value: guild.roles.cache.toJSON().join(', ') },
        );
      interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
    },
  };
```

Are there any ways around this that could be easy to come up with or is there a way to limit the listed roles that are displayed in any way?

Could there be a method of listing some roles and having the remaining ones show up after as something like '+ 7 other roles' for example?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a helper function that checks if the joined array's length is more than the max length:

```js
function generateTruncatedRoleList(roles) {
  // max char length is less than 1024,
  // so we can safely append "+N other roles"
  const MAX_CHARACTERS = 1000;
  // the character we're joining the arrays by
  const SEPARATOR = ', ';

  let roleList = [];
  let remainingRoles = 0;

  for (const role of roles) {
    roleList.push(role);

    if (roleList.join(SEPARATOR).length > MAX_CHARACTERS) {
      // remove the last role if it would be too long
      roleList.pop();
      remainingRoles = roles.length - roleList.length;
      
      break;
    }
  }

  if (remainingRoles > 0)
    roleList.push(
      `+${remainingRoles} other role${remainingRoles > 1 ? 's' : ''}`,
    );

  return roleList.join(SEPARATOR);
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```js
// ...
{
  name: 'Role List',
  value: generateTruncatedRoleList(guild.roles.cache.toJSON()),
},
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your explanations make it so much easier to understand!

Comment: Great, I'm glad I was able to help :)